# Formal way to send an HTTP body in PHP?

Tags: php, http

I'm writing my own `Response` class in PHP (as an exercise) in order to simplify the setting of headers and output. Currently, I'm using `header()` to send out HTTP headers after the request has been built but I'm not sure how to send the body. Do you just use `print` and `echo`? Or is there some a formal method?

Comment: Nope. Anything you output, is sent as part of the body.

Comment: Why would a function called `headers()` have anything to do with outputting the body?

Comment: @Brad — *like* headers (as in "`headers` outputs headers, is there a similar function to output body), not headers itself.

Comment: @TrentonMaki It sounds like you're looking for a web framework.  Many exist, and you can pick one for your specific requirements.  Check out Laravel for starters.  Also, remember that PHP is used for tasks outside of generating web pages.

Comment: @brad, thanks for the help! I'm actually trying to write my own (as an exercise). One of the classes I'm making is a formal `Response` object that you can add headers to and use to set the body of the actual response.

Comment: @TrentonMaki Add that to your question.  It's important.  If you wanted to go completely from scratch, you should be able to use the `php://output` stream.  If that doesn't work, you can try `php://stdout`, but it might behave different with a different SAPI.  I recommend writing your `Response` class, and have it use PHP's built-in header output.

Comment: @Brad I didn't even know those existed, thanks! I am currently using `header` to send out headers.

Comment: You should consider using output buffering as well, to ensure an eroneous echo somewhere higher up the calling code doesnt break your headers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Comment: @user574632 Thanks for the reference! I've touched on output buffers before but I haven't given them much time. I'll check that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [The HttpFoundation Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html)

A Response object holds all the information that needs to be sent back to the client from a given request. The constructor takes up to three arguments: the response content, the status code, and an array of HTTP headers:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response(
     'Content',
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    array('content-type' => 'text/html')
);
```

Comment: This is a solid class, but to clarify... it still uses the built-in PHP methods of `header()` and `echo`.  https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Response.php#L340

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not interested in using Symfony just yet.

Comment: You do not need to use the framework! Use only the component!

Comment: @gpupo Read the OP's question ("I'm writing my own Response class").

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen To be fair, I did not mention that I was writing my own response class until after gpupo posted his answer.

Comment: @TrentonMaki although you're not going to be using symfony, I advice you have a look at this specific page http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/book/http_fundamentals.html which explains how the HTTP protocol works as well as why/how the HttpFoundation is wrapped around it.

Comment: @tftd Thanks for the link! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `echo` is the way to go. However, it is a best practice to separate your logic and design. A good way to do this is by using two php files for 1 page (for example pagelogic.php and layout.php).